# Why is the reference to Swiper js in Elementor undefined?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, elementor

I added a slide widget to my elementor site. I want to change its functionality by using the swiper js library. The problem is that the swiper instance in javascript is returning undefined. Why am I unable to access swiper?

I used the method found here (https://developers.elementor.com/expose-swiper-in-elementor/) to reference the instance of swiper on my site.
Here's my code:

```
const mySlider = jQuery ( '#my-slider .swiper-container' );
console.log(mySlider);

    const swiperInstance = mySlider.data('swiper');
    
    console.log(swiperInstance);
```

the first console.log returned the slider element which is what I expected.
The issue is that the second console.log did not return the swiperInstance. Instead, it returned "undefined". So I am unable to make any changes to the instance.

Any help is very appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code snippet you provided, the issue seems to be with accessing the swiper instance using the **data('swiper')** method. The **data()** method retrieves data associated with the selected element, but it might not be the correct approach in this case.

To access the swiper instance, use the `Swiper` constructor directly. Here's an updated version of your code:

```js
const mySlider = jQuery('#my-slider .swiper-container');
console.log(mySlider);

const swiperInstance = new Swiper(mySlider[0]); // Initialize the swiper instance
console.log(swiperInstance);
```

We initialize a new instance of the **Swiper** class by passing the first element from `MySlider` using `mySlider[0]`.

If the problem still exists, try to dynamically load the script.

```js
const mySlider = jQuery('#my-slider .swiper-container');
console.log(mySlider);

// Dynamically load the Swiper library script
function loadScript(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.onload = resolve;
    script.onerror = reject;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });
}

// Load the Swiper library dynamically
loadScript('path/to/swiper.min.js')
  .then(() => {
    const swiperInstance = new Swiper(mySlider[0]); // Initialize the swiper instance
    console.log(swiperInstance);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Failed to load Swiper:', error);
  });
```

Comment: When trying this code, I get this error:  "uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined". Why isn't my code recognizing Swiper?

Comment: I am still completely stumped. Anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: It seems that swiper is not initialized when you try to get it.

Comment: I update my answer, you can see it.

Comment: didn't work for me. I'm going to skip this line of logic and tackle my problem an entirely different way. I'd still appreciate answers so I can know what to do next time...